# one json object per line with jq from a large json file

Tags: json, jq

Here is my json file :

```json
[
  {
    "name": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "3"
  },
  {
    "name": "4"
  }
]
```

i would like to get all object in a file one by line :

```
{"name":"1"}
{"name":"2"}
{"name":"3"}
{"name":"4"}
```

and my file is very big and i'am using the stream option.

Here is my attempt so far :

```
jq --stream -c '.[]' car.json > result.json
```

but it gives me :

```
[0,"name"]
"1"
[1,"name"]
"2"
```

Comment: just remove `--stream`(eg.using compact option is enough)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i don't have enough memory to remove the --stream options

Answer (score 1):

This topic is covered in the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#streaming-json-parser). For the situation you describe you might be able to use the simpler of the two possibilities given there:

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))'
```